# Capistrano restarts wrong version of puma when upgrading ruby version and puma

Tags: capistrano, puma

I'm upgrading a Rails application, deployed with capistrano and running puma, from ruby  2.2.0/puma 3.2 to ruby 2.3.1/puma 3.4.  When I deploy puma seems to be restarting in the wrong version.

Before my deploy, Puma is running under pid 4717 / version 3.4

```
vagrant@vagrant-master:/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids$ ps -ef | grep -i puma
vagrant   4717     1  0 20:53 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.4.0 (unix:///mnt/code/shared/tmp/sockets/code-puma.sock) [20160510205039]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
vagrant   4720  4717 12 20:53 ?        00:00:10 puma: cluster worker 0: 4717 [20160510205039]
```

When I deploy the old version (puma 3.2 / Ruby 2.2.0), puma restarts, its now running under pid 5466:

```
vagrant@vagrant-master:/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids$ ps -ef | grep -i puma
vagrant   5466     1  0 20:56 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.4.0 (unix:///mnt/code/shared/tmp/sockets/code-puma.sock) [20160510205440]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
vagrant   6154  5466  0 20:56 ?        00:00:00 puma: cluster worker 0: 5466 [20160510205440]
```

And my puma error log shows that its running 2.3.1 instead of 2.2.0

```
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:
in `block in materialize': Could not find active_attr-0.8.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

However, it should have switched to Puma 3.2/ruby 2.2.0.  When I force kill puma, it restarts (via monit) with the correct version (Puma 3.2 in this case)

```
vagrant@vagrant-master:/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids$ kill -9 5466

vagrant@vagrant-master:/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids$ ps -ef | grep -i puma
vagrant  17834     1  0 21:04 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.2.0 (unix:///mnt/code/shared/tmp/sockets/code-puma.sock) [20160510205440]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
vagrant  17837 17834 90 21:04 ?        00:00:01 puma: cluster worker 0: 17834 [20160510205440]
```

The relevant lines from the deploy log:

```
DEBUG [07f95004] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid ] as vagrant@vagrant-master
DEBUG [07f95004] Command: [ -f /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid ]
DEBUG [07f95004] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

DEBUG [42d98483] Running /usr/bin/env kill -0 $( cat /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid ) as vagrant@vagrant-master
DEBUG [42d98483] Command: kill -0 $( cat /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid )
DEBUG [42d98483] Finished in 0.007 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).

INFO [e81875a3] Running RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.0 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec pumactl -S /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state restart as vagrant@vagrant-master
DEBUG [e81875a3] Command: cd /mnt/code/current && ( export PATH="/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH" RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.2.0" RACK_ENV="vagrant" ; RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.2.0 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec pumactl -S /mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state restart )
DEBUG [e81875a3]    Command restart sent success
```

Here is part of my puma config in capistrano

```
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_preload_app, false
set :puma_prune_bundler, true
```

How can I deploy ruby-version and puma-version changes without having to kill the puma process?  Why does puma start with the wrong version?

Thanks

Comment: FWIW, running bundle exec cap puma:restart or bundle exec cap puma:phased-restart does not help - it still is running the wrong version after executing those commands.

Comment: cap puma:halt puma:start seems to do the trick for getting puma restarted, but its not seemless

Answer (score 0):

Check if `puma.rb` config file is specifying `puma.pid` and `puma.state` paths:

```
pidfile '/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid'
state_path '/mnt/code/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state'
```

Also check if `deploy/production.rb` is specifying that paths to:

```
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
```

I had a similar problem, and after setting this it worked well.

Comment: I have both those set - generally deploys restart puma workers just fine, but upgrading ruby and puma did not.